# Is pushing to a remote, the same as the remote pulling from you?

Tags: git

Assume you do a `git push remote_a` from `remote_b`. Is this the same as `git pull remote_b` from `remote_a`?

FYI: I'm trying to get a handle on the underlying mechanisms and improve my understanding of git. I have read many tutorials but feel almost as confused as when I first started!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though both does the same thing, push just pushes to remote where as pull is fetch+merge. To push from remote_a and to pull from remote_b you should have appropriate entries in the config file at each side.

Comment: So a push saves the recipient from downloading it when they go to pull it?

Comment: What do you mean regarding the appropriate entries in the config files?

Answer (score 0):

They are not exactly equal. The `pull` will merge the commits with the current branch, but `push` will not merge, and say "rejected".

For example, if X is the common commit

remote-a: X - A - B

remote-b: X - P - Q

```
remote-a >> git pull remote-b brach
```

will merge the two branches and you may have something like

X-A-B-P'-Q'

but this is not similar to

```
remote-b >> git push remote-a branch
```

which will say `!rejected`

Well, this the `Github` behavior. I have not worked with other remotes, but I guess the behavior of push and pull would remain the same.

A note from `git help push` for `-f.--force` flag

> Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an
>   ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. This flag
>              disables the check. This can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care.

Comment: `X-A-B-P'-Q'` would only be the resulting history if you were pulling with `--rebase` or had configuration options set to automatically rebase.